# WiFi works, but frequently disconnects with "authentication problem"

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a [**DOOGEE S60**](http://www.doogee.cc/detail/ip68-rugged-smartphone/112) with **Android 7.0 Nougat**.

It can connect to my 2.4GHz WiFi network at home without problems. However, quite frequently, the phone disconnects, showing the message "authentication problem" below the SSID. Manually reconnecting then temporarily fixes the problem, until the next random disconnect.

I have an **ASUS RT-AC66U** with Merlin firmware. The WiFi network uses WPA2-PSK+TKIP/AES. The phone is not rooted, and I'd like to keep it that way.

Observations:

- The phone maintains a stable WiFi connection on my company's network; this other network uses WPA2-PSK TKIP.
- Switching the WiFi on the phone off and on again, rebooting the router, rebooting the phone, forgetting and re-logging into the network, etc., all have no effect
- Same behavior occurs when using a 5GHz network (the ASUS router is dual-band)
- I have 23 other devices; they all connect to the same network without any problems whatsoever.
- The network does not employ MAC filtering or other such smoke-screen type security measures
- There is nothing relevant in the router's logs
- Disconnections occur completely randomly; sometimes I have difficulty maintaining a connection for longer than 2 minutes, sometimes it lasts the whole night.
- It *does* seem to be related to which apps are used. Particularly ad-infested apps seem to cause more frequent disconnections.

...I have no idea how to even begin diagnosing this extremely annoying problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks. In fact, I have a pretty good anti-intrusive-ad setup: I have a couple of scripts on the router that redirect connection attempts to known ad servers to an on-router installation of pixelserv. Together with an adblocker on the device itself, that works pretty well under most circumstances. However, things like the StumbleUpon app (which I rather like) directs all traffic through its servers, essentially bypassing my whole setup. So, it's not really the app that is ad-infested, but the naked, bare, uncensored internet. Yet, that is one app that seems to affect the problem.

Comment: @beeshyams but, even if I'm using NO APP AT ALL (e.g., after a fresh reboot), the problem persists...On a PC, I would consult a system log to try and identify the reason for the disconnection; what would be unrooted-Android equivalent? Is there one?

Comment: I am only aware of log cat which requires root. Let's wait for knowledgeable folks to suggest. Besides, if that app has permission to start on boot it needn't be activated to cause trouble ! If you can live without that app for ab day or two , uninstall that and see - if the problem is resolved, your problem statement is much simplified attacking that app. Also please add the ad blocker setup in your question, lest somebody suggest on similar lines (all don't read comments)